# Why is the definition of null function in Haskell Prelude so strange?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, compiler-optimization

The definition of `null` function in [Prelude](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) is the following:

```
null             :: [a] -> Bool
null []          =  True
null (_:_)       =  False
```

What confused me is the third line of the definition, why does it write:

```
null(_:_)        = False
```

Instead of:

```
null any = False
```

Does it have anything to do with the compiler optimization?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't matter. The definition makes it extremely clear that nothing was missed, but for lists that really isn't a big deal.

Comment: Also, you could define `null = all (const False)`. Perhaps that would be clearer.

Answer (score 5):

> Does it have anything to do with the compiler optimization?

No, in fact one can say that writing `null (_:_)` is less efficient than `null any` (in case the compiler does not optimizes this), since now you ask Haskell to verify that it is indeed the "cons". Although if a compiler does some bookkeeping on data types, it is of course easy to optimize this away. As far as I know, most compilers like `ghc` and almost *all compilers not written by three year old kids* indeed will do this.

First of all it is better **not** to write a wilcard `_` (or name it `any`) since the definition of a list (and any other datatype might change). Although for a list the odds are very unlikely, it could be possible that someone redefines a list. For instance like:

```
data [a] = [] | (a:[a]) | (Int///[a])
```

where for instance the latter pattern means that the list is repeated a number of times. In that case, a *compiler not written by a three year old kid :)* will warn that about *incomplete patterns for `null`*: it will thus claim that the `(_///_)` pattern was not specified. Whereas if you use a wildcard, it will fallback to the `null any` case.

In general one better uses wildcards with care: only in case you really do not care about what is given to the function, you should use wildcards.

Comment: It is *not* less efficient. The compiler *always* optimizes this.

Comment: @dfeuer: this is a weird claim, since no specific compiler is mentioned. I can write a Haskell compiler the other day that does not do this. My claim is not that a good compiler does not optimizes this. The idea is only that a syntactically, the former is less efficient. :)

Comment: There's no such thing as "syntactically less efficient". Decent compilers of statically typed languages with algebraic data types always do a good job of this. Remember that the compiler has to check that each constructor has the right type; while it's at it, it can easily check that all are present. This is much more complicated for GADTs, but those aren't relevant here.

Comment: If we want to be that pedantic, then "Haskell will warn about incomplete patterns" is also wrong-ish, since one can write a compiler which does not warn about that :-P. Worse, GHC does not warn about that by default. (I really wish non-exhaustive patterns were an error). Still, I always use `-Wall`, and the warning is very helpful, so I can understand the value of being explicit in the last pattern (even though I frequently write `_` there).

Comment: I agree with dfeuer. When you pattern match on `[]` you're checking whether the argument isn't cons. Hence, the second pattern match is free. You could either use a wildcard or you could write the pattern explicitly. It wouldn't matter. A good compiler like GHC would optimize it. If you think about it it's a pretty trivial thing to optimize.

Comment: @AaditMShah: yes of course. The problem is that my professor in Logic once told me that "a compiler" does not imply "a decent compiler" :) Of course this is pretty trivial. The point is that we can not say much about efficiency of matching, since as far as I know, nowhere in the specs of the language is it stated that this should be optimized that way.

Comment: @chi: fixed, better? :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is indeed so, that the pattern compiler is happy when it sees all data constructors of the type in question, and they are applied to  variables only.